# ESP8266 doesn't respond to AT commands

Tags: c++, esp8266, mbed, nucleo

I have a [Nucleo F103RB](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/nucleo-f103rb.html) and a [Sparkfun ESP8266](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13678).

I wanted to send AT commands to the ESP8266 through the Nucleo.

**The Wiring I used:**

```
TX  => D8
RX  => D2
GND => GND
3V3 => 3V3
```

I used `D8` and `D2` of Serial1 because  `D0` and `D1` pins are not available per default as they are used by the STLink Virtual Comm Port. I also tried `D10` instead of `D8` as well as putting `RST` on `3V3` and inverting `TX` and `RX`

**Here is the code I have on mbed:**

```
#include "mbed.h"

Serial pc (D1, D0);  
Serial esp(D8, D2);

int main() 
{
    pc.baud(115200);
    esp.baud(115200);
    wait(0.1);
    pc.printf("start\r\n");
    esp.printf("AT+RST\r\n");
    while(true) {
        if(pc.readable()) {
            char c = pc.getc();
            pc.putc(c); //local echo
            esp.putc(c);
        }
        if(esp.readable()) {
            pc.printf("reading esp");
            char c = esp.getc();
            pc.putc(c);
        }
    }
}
```

I used `Serial` instead of `RawSerial` because `RawSerial` wasn't working at all for me, I'm not sure why.

The ESP8266 module doesn't respond to [any AT command available to the factory firmware](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/WiFi/Command%20Doc.pdf). `esp.readable()` returns false no matter what and `esp.printf("AT+RST\r\n");` doesn't do anything.

The board is brand new and the LEDs work fine.

Comment: ESP-01 needs more than those 4 wires.

Comment: At this point I tried most wirings you'd find online. Most of them do use 4 wires only and bridge RST to VCC.

Answer (score 0):

Wire the ESP module [like this](https://github.com/ARMmbed/dsa-2017/raw/master/img/pinout-esp8266.jpg) - so CH_PD also to high. After you can use [SerialPassthrough](https://os.mbed.com/users/mbedAustin/code/SerialPassthrough/file/96cb82af9996/main.cpp/) to verify whether the module works (set baud rate to 115,200 on both).

Optionally also wire the RESET pin of the module to a digital pin. Useful to reset the ESP module (pull low, then pull high to reset).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. Although I do have a message saying "Ai-Thinker Technology Co. Ltd. 
Ready" when I reset it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

Contrary to what you might find online in several documentations including mbed's, using character per character passthrough won't work because the module will interpret each character one by one. Using `puts` instead of `putc` solved my issue.